# FastCube 2 in Delphi, hide total for a measure

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am using FastCube 2.0 with Delphi.

I have cube and a slice... I need to hide TOTAL for one column (measure). How do I access it in code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
fcxSliceSLICENAME.MeasuresContainer.Measures[0].UseDifferentAggForTotals := True;
fcxSliceSLICENAME.MeasuresContainer.Measures[0].AgrFuncForTotals := af_Formula;

(0 indicates index of the column whose total you want to hide)